# Contact starting with a specific alphabet

Tags: android

I want to get all the contact starting with the alphabet. Example contact starting with A Is there any way to find that...

Now I am using the code

```
String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following..

```
managedQuery (Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder);

Cursor cursor = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, 
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME + " = ?", 
            new String[] { "A" }, null);
```

This method was deprecated in API level 11.If it works ok., or otherwise use the below.

```
CursorLoader (Context context, Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder);
```